# Pre-requisites for JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using Aptana Studio 1.5 for PHP development. I want to use a JQuery plug-in. I want to know whether there are any pre-requisites for using JQuery or is it same as JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is a library written using javascript. you can reduce the  lengthy code  which u usually have in your javascript with the use of jquery. thats y its called "Write Less ,Do More Library".

You can have animations ,fading,DOM traversing,ajax calls etc..by simple function calls using jQuery.

Moreover there are lot of pluggins written for jquery, you can use whatever you need as per your requirement,

For using jQuery in your project,Simply download the stable version from the jquery site and include that in your page as you do for normal javascript file.

[Official jquery site](http://jquery.com/)

[Pluggin page](http://plugins.jquery.com/)

You will definitely love jquery once start using.You will not leave it for sure as i do .
Hats off to jQuery team

Answer (score 2):

The [jQuery browser compatibility](http://docs.jquery.com/Browser_Compatibility) page lists the minimum browsers that are supported as:

- Firefox 2.0+
- Internet Explorer 6+
- Safari 3+
- Opera 9+
- Chrome 1+

A jQuery plugin generally supports the same browsers as long as it only uses jQuery methods, however some may use CSS features that are not supported by all browsers. Check if the plugin has any specific compatibility notes, but a lot of plugins are not as well tested as the jQuery library itself.

Answer (score 1):

I've never struck a pre-req for using jQuery itself. All it needs is a Javascript implementation.

There may be pre-reqs for specific add-ons to jQuery but that will depend on the add-on itself.

I've used it successfully on Firefox 2 and 3 and IE6 and 7 - I don't know if you'll strike any problems with IE8 but I imagine they'd be fixed up pretty fast.